# EC2 Enchant Can't Find Dictionary en_US

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, pyenchant

I'm trying to run the command `d = enchant.Dict('en_US')` but am getting an error message `"enchant.errors.DictNotFoundError: Dictionary for language 'en_US' could not be found"`

I've run the command `sudo yum install aspell -en` and tried setting the param path `"enchant.set_param("enchant.aspell.dictionary.path","/usr/lib64/aspell-0.60")"` to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

I had to run `yum install aspell-en enchant-aspell` before I could get it working. Notice there is no space in "aspell-en".

enchant-aspell includes "Integration with aspell for libenchant", allowing enchant and aspell to talk to each other. Hope this help.